# socket opening error : Invalid argument: create with JDK 1.6u37

Tags: java, windows, sockets, java-native-interface, socketexception

I have the following issue. I have a java .jar who is used by a cpp program (visual studio) and a java application.

I use a connect method to connect to a target. With the java library and the cpp program the connect failed with the following issue :

java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument: create

```
    at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:397)

    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:527)

    at com.alcatel.microwave.net.tcp.client.TcpClient.doConnectWithTimeout(TcpClient.java:322)

   [...]
```

On the same computer, the connection is successful with the java application who use the same library (so the same connect function).

Some precisions :

- the code is located and run on Clearcase view
- there is computer who run the code without issue
- I tried to add the following option : options[5].optionString = "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true";
- I access the JVM with JNI when I have the issue.

Thanks in advance

Here a little example :

```
try
{

Socket connectionSocket = new Socket();   
connectionSocket.connect( serverAddress, timeout );

}

catch( Exception e )
{
    synchronized( this )
    {
        connectionSocket = null;
    }

    if( logger.isDebugEnabled() )
    {     
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.debug( e.getMessage() );
    }   
}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I updated my post. please tell me if you need more info / sample.

Comment: maybe this is related: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068568

Comment: @WatchdogReset any idea on how to solve this kind of issue? I am also facing similar issue.

Comment: I do not remember very well. I have solved the issue. I think this was related to mutliple JDK version on my PC and JNI using one different from the one I expected. To solve the issue I have hardcoded the path of the loaded JVM. If it does not soleve your issue tell me more details please

Comment: Thanks for information.